# Different c# dll loading behaviours between debug and release mode

Tags: .net, winforms, debugging, dll, release

I created a little winform c# program to demonstrate the problem. It's a Visual Studio project with a reference for MySql.Data.dll:

Form1.cs

```
namespace DynamicLoadingTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int i = 9;
            if (i == 10)
            {
                System.Data.Common.DbCommand cmd = MySQLInterface.GetMySQLCommand();
            }
        }
    }
    public class MySQLInterface
    {
        public static System.Data.Common.DbCommand GetMySQLCommand()
        {
            return new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
namespace DynamicLoadingTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

The designer file for Form1.cs contains nothing special, just the default template from vs2015.

We are using Process Explorer from Mark Russinovich to analyze the executed file:

- in debug mode, MySql.Data.dll is not part of the executed file
- in release mode, MySql.Data.dll was loaded

Why?

Comment: I see MySql.Data.dll in both when running in both Debug & Release. Can you share output from Process explorer for those two cases. Maybe save to the file and share?

Comment: Before comparing these data i uploaded our little project for an additional test [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bfuxdawiji711t6/DynamicLoading.rar?dl=0). We are using Visual Studio 2015, .NET Version 4.5.2, Process Explorer 15.11 - do you still see the dll in both modes ?

Comment: with the code from Dropbox it doesn't load dll in any case as if never is satisfied (i never equal 10). If expression is changed to be satisfied (int i = 9) then the dll is visible in both debug & release. Process Explorer 16.05

Comment: That's the effect we wanted to trigger! But what could be the reason for the different dll loading behaviour?

Comment: I don't see any different. In both cases (Debug, Release) there either MySQL.dll loaded or not.